# How to change the integral variable and integral upper/lower limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, warning-messages

I am dealing with the symbolic operation of taking the antiderivative, e.g., `Integrate[f, x]`  (where $f$ represents  a  complicated function which cannot return integral value directly)

I want to change the integral variable $x \mapsto x+a$，so I simply `% /. x-> y + a`. The result was that the form of integral seemly change to `Integrate[f, y + a]`

But this produces the error:

> Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in y + a.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I tell Mathematica to deal with the change of integral variable automatically? That is, how produce the change of $d(y + a)$ to $dy$.
2. In a definite integral, is there some ways to change the integral upper and lower limits automatically in the same way as I want to change the integral variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following should work.  Beginning with

```
int = Integrate[f[x], {x, b, c}];
```

Then,

```
int /. {f[x] -> f[x - a], {x, b, c} -> {x, b + a, c + a}}
(* Integrate[f[-a + x], {x, a + b, a + c}]  *)
```

shifts `x` by `a` while leaving the value of the integral unchanged.  For instance,

```
Integrate[Sin[x], {x, b, c}]
(* Cos[b] - Cos[c] *)

Unevaluated[Integrate[Sin[x], {x, b, c}]] /. {Sin[x] -> Sin[x - a], 
    {x, b, c} -> {x, b + a, c + a}}
(* Cos[b] - Cos[c] *)
```

as expected.  (`Unevaluated` is used to prevent this simple integral from being evaluated before the change of argument and limits.)  If changing the argument and limits independently is desired, then use something like

```
int /. {f[x] -> f[x - a], {x, b, c} -> {x, b + u, c + v}}
```

or whatever is desired.

Comment: But if the change of integral is more complex, e.g. $x \mapsto -x$, then it will return a negative sign after above operations. Do I have to multiple such coefficient manually？

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

A simple replacement of the variable won't do if you want to perform general integration by substitution. We can define a function like the following for this task:

```
intSub[x_ -> g_, y_][expr_] := 
 expr /. {Integrate[f_, x] :> Integrate[(f /. x -> g) D[g, y], y], 
   Integrate[f_, {x, a_, b_}] :> 
    Integrate[(f /. x -> g) D[g, y], 
     Prepend[y /. Solve[g == x, y][[1]] /. {{x -> a}, {x -> b}}, y]]}
```

Applications:

```
Integrate[f[x], x] // intSub[x -> y + a, y]
```

$\int f(a+y) \, dy$

```
Integrate[f[x], x] // intSub[x -> -y, y]
```

$-\int f(-y) \, dy$

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] // intSub[x -> g[y], y]
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
```

$\int_{g^{(-1)}(a)}^{g^{(-1)}(b)} f(g(y)) g'(y) \, dy$

Note that the change of upper and lower limits only works as expected if `Solve[g == x, y][[1]]` works out the correct inverse of `x = g(y)`.